# Maximizing $\int\limits_{-1}^1x^3f(x)~dx$ where $f$ satisfies some properties

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Find the maximum of $\int\limits_{-1}^1x^3f(x)~dx$ for real-valued measurable functions $f(x)$ satisfying 
$$\int\limits_{-1}^1 |f(x)|^2~dx=1$$
$$\int\limits_{-1}^1f(x)~dx=\int\limits_{-1}^1 x f(x)~dx=\int\limits_{-1}^1 x^2 f(x)~dx=0.$$

My guess is to use Lusin's theorem and Stone-Weierstrass theorem, but then I do not know how to maximize the integral over all polynomials satisfying these conditions. I may have overlooked the properties of some orthogonal polynomials.

Comment: Study simple functions satisfying the conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) given an orthogonal base of $L^2(-1,1)$ with respect to the standard inner product. Assuming
$$ f(x)\stackrel{L^2}{=}\sum_{n\geq 0}c_n P_n(x) \tag{1}$$
the given constraints can be written as
$$ c_0=c_1=c_2=0,\qquad \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{2c_n^2}{2n+1}=1 \tag{2} $$
hence the solution is given by a multiple of $P_3(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(5x^3-3x\right)$, namely $\pm\sqrt{\frac{7}{2}}\,P_3(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Using Lagrange multipliers, let 
$$ F(f, \lambda_0, \lambda_1, \lambda_2, \mu) = 
\int_{-1}^{1} f(x) (x^3 + \mu f(x) + \lambda_0  + \lambda_1 x + \lambda_2 x^2) \; dx $$
Then by taking the variation with respect to $f(x)$, we should have 
$$ x^3 + 2 \mu f(x) + \lambda_0 + \lambda_1 x + \lambda_2 x^2 = 0$$
i.e. $f(x)$ is a cubic polynomial that satisfies the constraints.

That polynomial turns out to be $\pm \frac{\sqrt{14}}{4} (5 x^3 - 3 x)$.  For a maximum, you want the $\pm$ to be $-$.

Comment: [Lagrange multipliers on Banach spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multipliers_on_Banach_spaces)